# Python sort with key implementation

Tags: python, sorting

I was experimenting with python sorting using key.
I'm interested in the inner working of the algorithm.
Is it roughly equivalent to Schwartzian transform [(Decorate-Sort-Undecorate)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#The_Old_Way_Using_Decorate-Sort-Undecorate)?

Specifically:

- The spec keys are extracted only once. Can it be asssumed that this happens before any comparisions occur?
- How are the extracted keys maintained in memory? As tuples `(key, orginal_value)` or does it use some other method.

I used the following test program

```py
class Isbn:
    def __init__(self, isbn_num):
        self.isbn_num = isbn_num

    def __lt__(self, other):
        print(f"__lt__ {self.isbn_num} {other.isbn_num}")
        return self.isbn_num < other.isbn_num

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'Isbn({self.isbn_num})'


class Book:
    def __init__(self, isbn):
        self.isbn = Isbn(isbn)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'Book({self.isbn})'

    @property
    def key(self):
        print(f"key {self.isbn}")
        return self.isbn


books = [Book(5), Book(10), Book(6), Book(2)]
books.sort(key=lambda b: b.key)
print(books)
```

Which gives the following output:

```
key Isbn(5)
key Isbn(10)
key Isbn(6)
key Isbn(2)
__lt__ 10 5
__lt__ 6 10
__lt__ 6 10
__lt__ 6 5
__lt__ 2 6
__lt__ 2 5
[Book(Isbn(2)), Book(Isbn(5)), Book(Isbn(6)), Book(Isbn(10))]
```

Comment: That's a nice experiment you've performed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking specifically about CPython (other implementations of Python are available):

It does do the transform.  It currently builds a C-array of keys before it starts to sort.  This is done entirely in C - so it's not a Python list. No Python tuples are involved.

This is an excerpt from the (current) relevant C code (though of course this will change as CPython evolves), taken from `listobject.c`.

`key_func` is the key function.  `saved_ob_size` is the length of the list. `saved_ob_item` is the array from the original list.

```
2239 if (keyfunc == NULL) { 
         ...
2243     } 
2244     else { 
         ...    
2256         for (i = 0; i < saved_ob_size ; i++) { 
2257             keys[i] = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(keyfunc, saved_ob_item[i], 
2258                                                    NULL); 
                 ...
2265             } 
2266         }
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks to your answer, I was able to find the actual issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue9915 and changset: https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/98338227a7fe2ebb3e820c547ab05af259320642

Answer (score 1):

Yes Python does use the `Schwartzian transform` in some cases.
From [this documentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Schwartzian_transform#Python).

> Python programmers use the transform in sorts where the comparison operation may be expensive.

Comment: But does the sort use a Schwartzian transform?

Comment: This is not the point, I crafted my example to have a hook into `__lt__`. Your answer does not address any of my questions.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I got a link where it tells about Python sorting and the transform, let me look more into this!